# Create EFI-stub boot entry from Windows

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, bcdedit

I use Linux kerne EFI stub to boot. Now I have run into an emergency, because I have lost my UEFI boot entry and I am stuck with Windows.

Is there any possibility to create UEFI NVRAM boot entry for Linux kernel?

I have managed to create it, but without kernel args (like: root=PARTUUID=....) and Linux is not booting without them.

Is there a way how to create boot menu entry from Windows 10 with CLI args?

Comment: Emergency resolved with live Linux. But the question is still relevant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be:

1. [Mount the ESP partition under windows](https://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write).
2. [Create a `startup.nsh` script to pass kernel parameters](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFISTUB#Using_a_startup.nsh_script)
3. Create boot menu entry which points to the `startup.nsh`

Answer (score 0):

#### One way you can resolve this:

You can run any live linux OS, chroot to your still existing installed Linux Distribution, and reinstall grub, which will re-add Linux to the boot menu alongside Windows.

Comment: I am not using GRUB nor any other bootloader. EFI-stub is a GRUBless way to boot Linux kernel on bare metal :). I can use live Linux to recreate the boot record. The only problem is that I have no USB drive availible.

Answer (score 0):

You might try efibooteditor, a GUI/CLI tool to read/write EFI boot entries on Windows (or Linux). https://github.com/Neverous/efibooteditor/